# How to change select2 width dynamically after init

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a kind of info panel on the right side of my apps page.
This panel can be resized in width by dragging and moving the border (E.g. Like you can resize the columns in a windows finder)
In the panel I have a select2 to search for something. I initialize this select2 with

```
    let infoPanelSiteId = $('#infoPanelSiteId');
    infoPanelSiteId.select2(
        {
            ajax:
                {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    url: BACKEND_URL + '/infopanel/searchsites.php',
                    processResults: function (data)
                    {
                        return {results: data.data};
                    }
                },
            width: infoPanel.width - 15,
            placeholder: i18next.t('default:infopanel.site.search')
        })
        .on('change', function ()
        {
            let data = infoPanelSiteId.select2('data');
            if (data[0])
            {
                data = data[0];
                InfoPanel.setInfoPanelSiteById(data.id);
            }
        });
```

Now if the user resizes the info panel the select2 is not resizing because it has a fixed width.
Problem is, that the display of the panel is using display: table and display: table-cell which is necessary on other purposes. So I cannot work with width: 100% or width: auto because a table cell does ignore a css width.

So I look for a possibility to change the inlined width in the select2 container

```
select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below
```

I tried it with

```
$('#infoPanelSiteId').next().css('width' : (infopanel.width -10) + 'px !important');
```

and

```
$('.select2-container--below').css('width' : (infopanel.width -10) + 'px !important');
```

but that does not work.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Here is a fiddle how it should work but it doesnt

https://jsfiddle.net/wazrdky2/

Comment: Adding a css to parent page doesn't solve the issue for u? Like to set the css in body instead for the required element class using /deep/

Comment: Sometimes its the package's code itself which sets the css via js so trying to override it may not give u the desired results as you can't really see what's actually happening in there.

Comment: I would suggest you to try changing it through the normal css and define it in the body scope and handle the resize requirements via media queries. I'm sure you can access the element via css like `body >>> .select2-container--below`

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand. I need to set the width to values from 100-300px and each pixel in-between. So I cannot create css styles for each width. Can you please give me a detailed answer on how you think I can solve it?

Comment: I mean try changing the css selectors in your code to `body >>> .select2...` or whatever the accessible immediate parent of select2 container is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change the width when the class `select2-container--below` appears do that: (event open and close)

```
$('#yourselect2ID').on('select2:open', function (e) {
   $("body > span.select2-container--below").css("width", "600px");
});
```

```js
$('#example').select2();



$('#example').on('select2:open', function (e) {
   $("body > span.select2-container--below").css("width", "100px");
});

$('#example').on('select2:close', function (e) {
   $("body > span.select2-container--below").css("width", "300px");
});

//$('#example').select2({dropdownCssClass : 'bigdrop'});
```

```css
.bigdrop {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Bat">Bat</option>
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Elephant">Elephant</option>
    <option value="View/Exposure">View/Exposure</option>
    <option value="View / Exposure">View / Exposure</option>
    <option value="Dummy - Data">Dummy - Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy-Data">Dummy-Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy:Data">Dummy:Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy(Data)">Dummy(Data)</option>    
</select>

  </body>
</html>
```

or you could use Custom CSS style like this:

```
$('#yourselect2ID').select2({dropdownCssClass : 'bbbdrop'});

.bbbdrop {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

```js
$('#example').select2({dropdownCssClass : 'bigdrop'});
```

```css
.bigdrop {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Bat">Bat</option>
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Elephant">Elephant</option>
    <option value="View/Exposure">View/Exposure</option>
    <option value="View / Exposure">View / Exposure</option>
    <option value="Dummy - Data">Dummy - Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy-Data">Dummy-Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy:Data">Dummy:Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy(Data)">Dummy(Data)</option>    
</select>

  </body>
</html>
```

you could mix both:

```js
$('#example').select2({dropdownCssClass : 'bigdrop'});

$('#example').on('select2:open', function (e) {
   $("body > span.select2-container--below").css("width", "100px");
});

$('#example').on('select2:close', function (e) {
   $("body > span.select2-container--below").css("width", "300px");
});
```

```css
.bigdrop{
    width: 100px !important;

}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Bat">Bat</option>
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Elephant">Elephant</option>
    <option value="View/Exposure">View/Exposure</option>
    <option value="View / Exposure">View / Exposure</option>
    <option value="Dummy - Data">Dummy - Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy-Data">Dummy-Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy:Data">Dummy:Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy(Data)">Dummy(Data)</option>    
</select>

  </body>
</html>
```

if you want dynamically set the width of select2, without reinitializing it: (change the selector)

```js
    let width = 300;
    
    let infoPanelSiteId = $('#infoPanelSiteId');
        infoPanelSiteId.select2(
            {
                
                width: "resolve",
                placeholder: 'Placeholder'
            })
            .on('change', function ()
            {
            });

    let interval = setInterval(() =>
  {
    width +=10;
    
        $(".infopanelPanel span.select2-container").css("width", width + "px");
    if(width == 500)
        clearInterval(interval);
  }, 500);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <div class = "infopanelPanel">
        <div class = "infoPanelTitleDiv">
            <div class = "infoPanelTitleText">
                <label><select id = "infoPanelSiteId" class = "editSelect" style="width:400px">
                     <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
                      <option value="Bat">Bat</option>
                      <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
                      <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
                </select></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps I have not made clear enough what I try to achieve. ITs not about the dropdown box but also of the select itself. I have added a fiddle to my question, so you may help to make it work

Comment: Yes reinitializing is something I already did but this is a real overhead as the resize event comes with every mousemove when dragged. But if this is the only way I need to go it. thanks

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff  ok i have updated my last snippet no reinitialization, set resolve in width and set the right selector, i begin with 400px defined in html style and then adjust

Comment: Thanks a lot. That’s what I was searching for